# Function returning a table used in a SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a function returning a table, defined like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(IN id_in bigint) RETURNS TABLE (
    out_1 bigint,
    out_2 text
) AS
$$
BEGIN
    -- Do something and return the appropriate result
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(1)
```

It returns a table, as expected. However, I would like to use it to do something a little more advanced, like:

```
SELECT my_function(id) FROM some_table;
```

The query works, but I have a little trouble working with the result. It returns a set of records, like:

> (1,text_1)
>
> (2,text_2)

etc.

It's expected behavior, however is there a way to "unpack" these records into a "normal" table, just like the one a `SELECT * FROM` returns?

Comment: Functions returning  a table should **only** be used in the `from` clause. What exactly are you trying to do? Please edit your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: If they should be used only in the `FROM` clause that basically answers my question, but I'll supplement it accourdingly in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lateral join](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#LATERAL_JOIN). A function used in FROM clause is lateral by default:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM some_table, my_function(id) AS f;
```